# Precedence order between ++ and = in Java

Tags: java, computer-science

According to https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

++ is higher priority than =

But the code below. count prints out 0 instead of 1.

I thought `int count = F[0]++;`,

1. get the value of F[0]
2. ++ is applied to this value 0 which becomes 1
3. then this increased value is assigned to count.

But it's not. To print out 1, should be `int count = ++F[0];`

OMG, have I misunderstood embarrassingly such extremely basic thing for a long time? 
This is 101 for a freshman in college question, but can someone please let me why this prints out 0 instead of 1?

```
        int[] F = new int[26];
        int count = F[0]++;
        System.out.println(count);      // count is 0  (instead of 1) !!!
```

Comment: Yes, but `++` operator os post-incrementation, so it's job is NOT to get the value after computation

Comment: i = 0; `int a = i++` will set `a` to `0`. `int a = ++i` will set `a` to `1`. First one is post-increment which happens after statement completion. and second is `pre-increment` which happens before statement completion.

Answer (score 1):

The assignement happens **before** the post-increment - that's why it's called *post-increment*. Therefore `count` becomes `0` but if you print out `F[0]`, its value would be `1`.

```
int[] F = new int[26];       // F[0] is 0 (default value)
int count = F[0]++;          // F[0] is 0, 
                             // then count = F[0], therefore count = 0
                             // then F[0] is 1 (post-incremented)
System.out.println(count);   // count is not affected and remains 0
```

Comment: This isn't technically true; the code `int y = x++;` compiles to `iload_1`, `iinc 1, 1`, `istore_2`, so the increment happens before the store. It's just that the store uses the value which was loaded by `iload_1` before the increment occurs.

Comment: Yeah, I was describing from an observation of a developer side. I have no clue about the compiled bytecode. Thanks for a lesson :)

Comment: Sure! In practice it only makes a difference for tricky code like `int y = (x++) + (x++);` where the first increment has its effect before the second increment is performed, so if `x` starts as 0 then the value of the first `x++` is 0 and the value of the second is 1, leaving y = 1. That shows that the value of x has changed before y gets assigned, but it's better not to write code like this anyway.

Comment: Thanks @kaya3 your answer what I needed.

Comment: @Andreas: A typo fixed. :)